# Custom Grafana panels greyed out

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I wrote an exporter to export my statistics to Prometheus and then I created some simple graphs in Grafan for them. When I create a graph they are working but as soon as I save and close the dashboard and open it again all the graphs/panels greyed out (as it can be seen). I checked the logs of Grafana but there is no log related to this. What is the problem or at least how I can debug this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inspecting the browser I found the problem and the solution is https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/10950#issuecomment-371555881